# Java Swing: Spinning Image Animation

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am trying to create spinning image Animation but something seems to be not working in the code. I am rotating image at various angles and drawing it but at the end I only end up single rotated image than animation. Is this possible to do in Java or do I need switch to C# Unity where I found multiple examples on doing so nothing so far in Java. I am new to Swing so I would really appreciate simplified answer.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Rotate extends JPanel {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Rotate().go();
    }
    
    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotate");
        JButton b = new JButton("click");
        
        MyDrawPanel p = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        } 
        
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
        Image image = new ImageIcon(
                getClass()
                .getResource("wheel.png"))
                .getImage();
        
        public void animateCircle(Graphics2D g2d ) {
            //g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(25), 250, 250);
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500, this);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //super.paintComponent(g);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
            animateCircle(g2d);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried moving for loop in the paintComponent() method but it didn't help either.

Comment: you __must not__ sleep the EDT - learn how to  use the swing version  of Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
    public void animateCircle(Graphics2D g2d ) {
        //g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(25), 250, 250);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500, this);
    }
```

You rotation is fixed, so you aren't seeing your image spinning

By changing your value in Math.toRadians(...), you can make it appear to spin

This

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    rotationStep ++;
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
    } 
  }
```

Is the wrong way to do animation in swing. The right way is to use a javax.swing.Timer

```
public class MyTimer implements ActionListener {
  int rotationStep = 0;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
//    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    rotationStep ++;
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using rotationStep as parameter to Math.Radians(). It rotates only when I resize window but otherwise its constant. Thanks

Comment: @riar That probably means that you haven't get the Swing Timer set up correctly. It should show rotation on timer tick if you are updating the rotationStep and then calling repaint();

Comment: @riar I would like to ask you to purge yourself of `degrees` as a unit of measurement :-) Radians are a more useful measure (see this math problem I solved using radians: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265354/calculating-the-break-even-point-between-traveling-around-the-inner-outer-circ) but also using radians (which are based in the circumference of a unit circle) you don't need to introduce the earth-centric 360 constant, which came from the Babylonian calendar, and is related to and 365 days in the year - on earth (https://www.historytoday.com/history-matters/full-circle)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I used swing timer and called repaint on panel and its working fine. Now my next is to calculate where does wheel stop and display particular result. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  I reorganized some of your code which you can of course change at your leisure.  Most of the critical elements are documented within the code. Major changes include:

- eliminating magic numbers - allows alterations to happen in one place
- using `Rendering hints` to eliminate rotating images.
- overridding `getPreferredSize()` in the panel class
- computing panel size to allow full rotation within panel.
- using a swing timer to control repaint and angle updates

```
public class Rotate extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Rotate().go();
    }

  

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotate");
        JButton b = new JButton("click");
        
        File file = new File("wheel.png");
        try {
             image = ImageIO
                    .read(new FileInputStream(new File("H:/Bench.jpg")));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // invoke an instance of the panel with the image
        MyDrawPanel p = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        
        // center the frame on the screen
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        // start the animation
        p.animateCircle();
       
    }
    

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        double angle = 0;
        //increment of the angle of rotation
        double inc = Math.toRadians(.1);
        int imageWidth;
        int imageHeight;
        int panelWidth;
        int panelHeight;
        
        double ctrX;
        double ctrY;
        int startX;
        int startY;
        
        @Override 
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(panelWidth, panelHeight);
        }
        
        public MyDrawPanel() {
            double imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            double imageHeight = image.getHeight();
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            
            // compute panel size to allow full rotation within by computing
            //the image's diagonal length
            panelWidth = (int)Math.hypot(imageWidth, imageHeight);
            panelHeight = panelWidth;
            
            //target location for writing object (upper left corner)
            startX = (int)(panelWidth-imageWidth)/2;
            startY = (int)(panelHeight-imageHeight)/2;
            
            // center of rotation
            ctrX = panelWidth/2;
            ctrY = panelHeight/2;
           
        }
        
       
        // This starts the animation using a swing timer to update the angle and repaint the image
        public void animateCircle() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(0, (ae)-> { 
                angle += inc; repaint();
            });
            
            timer.setDelay(10);
            timer.start();
           
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            
            // setting the rendering hints allows smooth rotation of images with minimal distortion
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            
            // rotate the graphics context about the center
            g2d.rotate(angle, ctrX, ctrY);
            
            // draw the image. Top left at startX and startY 
            g2d.drawImage(image, startX, startY, this);
           
        }
    }
}
```

Note:  If the timer is set to a low value (faster rotation) and the image is too large, the image may not finish the current rotation cycle before the timer re-fires.